# Get the javascript errors that are printed to browser console

Tags: javascript, browser

Is there a way to catch the errors that are written to the console (e.g `unrecognized token`) in code? I want to write them to a log of some kind.

Answer (score 0):

You can listen to the [`window`'s onerror event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onerror).

```
window.onerror = function(errorMsg, url, lineNumber, charNumber, errObj) {
  alert(errObj.message);
};
abc();
```

This will afaik only be emitted if there is run time errors in loaded files.

You should be able to return `false` to prevent the original error from showing.

Comment: Hi dev, I tried your approach, but there is still a problem. In the alert I get "Script error." while to the console it says "Uncaught ReferenceError: myFalseParam is not defined". I want to get the same message as in the console, there is no much to do with the other one.

Comment: @GM6 It seams that you get the error object as the fifth argument in Chrome, idk about other browsers though.